# Add git head count to CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, git, bash

I am trying combine the git head count and bundle version to look like CFBundleShortVersionString-githeadcount . Here is the code which I am using right now:

```
GIT_RELEASE_VERSION=$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)
COMMITS=$(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l)
#COMMITS=$(($COMMITS))
defaults write "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH%.*}" "CFBundleShortVersionString" "${GIT_RELEASE_VERSION#*v}"
defaults write "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH%.*}" "CFBundleVersion" "${COMMITS}"
```

Comment: Just a note: git itself uses `GIT_` prefix environment variables, and constructs like `eval unset ${!GIT_*}` get used to e.g. recursively invoke git on another repo from inside a repo hook.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
COMMITS=$(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l)
COMMITS=$(($COMMITS))
defaults write "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH%.*}" "CFBundleVersion" "${buildNumber} - ${COMMITS}"
```

Comment: `COMMITS=$(git rev-list --count HEAD)`.